# Set .travis.yml to automatically deploy docker image

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment, travis-ci

I am deploying a web app written in python (flask) in Docker container to Heroku using Travis-CI. How to set up travis.yml to deploy an image to Heroku automatically?

I am able to login to Docker and push the image there automatically.

My .travis.yml:

```
language: python
sudo: required

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t quarkus7/which-tram .

script:
  - docker run quarkus7/which-tram python test.py

after_success:
  - bash docker_hub_push
  - docker tag quarkus7/which-tram registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME/web
  - docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME/web
  - ( echo "$HEROKU_USERNAME" echo "$HEROKU_PASSWORD" ) | heroku login -i
  - heroku container:login
  - heroku container:release web --app $HEROKU_APP_NAME
```

However I get an error in Travis log:

```
$ ( echo "$HEROKU_USERNAME" echo "$HEROKU_PASSWORD" ) | heroku login -i
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email: Password: sh: 1: read: Illegal option -s
```

Do you know how to amend .travis.yml in order to login to Heroku and release the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some methods: [Script "heroku login" in a CI environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554697/script-heroku-login-in-a-ci-environment). I think you can try `Method 2: Environment Variable`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can login to push to the heroku registry:

#### .travis.yml:

```
before_install:
- wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh #installed heroku CLI
- docker login -u "$HEROKU_USERNAME" --password=$(heroku auth:token) registry.heroku.com #logged in
```

`$HEROKU_USERNAME` is your Heroku e-mail.

And then, deploy using `heroku container:release` like this:

```
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: 
    heroku container:release web --app your-app-name
```