# Login to Heroku within Jenkins Pipeline script

Tags: node.js, jenkins, heroku, command-line-interface

I am new to Jenkins and docker and came across this dilemma, I have this simple pipeline script,

```
pipeline {
agent any
tools {nodejs "node"}
environment { 
    VERSION = "${env.BUILD_ID}-${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
}
stages {
    stage('Set up Heroku'){
        steps{
            bat "npm install -g heroku"
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId:'herokuid',usernameVariable:'USR',passwordVariable:'PWD')]){
                    bat '(echo "${env.USR}" echo "${env.PWD}") | heroku login -i'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Cloning Git') {
        steps {
            git 'https://github.com/enoch17/ubiquitous-octo-potato.git'
        }
    }
    stage('Install Packages') {
        steps {
            bat 'npm install'
        }
    }
    stage('Test'){
        steps{
            bat 'npm test'
        }
    }
    stage('Build Docker Image'){
        steps{
            bat 'docker build -t enocho/jenkinstest:1 .'
        }
    }
    stage('Docker Login'){
        steps{
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId:'dockerid',usernameVariable:'USR',passwordVariable:'PWD')])
            {
                bat "docker login -u=${env.USR} -p=${env.PWD}"
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Push Docker Image'){
        steps{
            bat "docker push enocho/jenkinstest:latest"
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy Docker Image'){
        steps{

                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId:'herokuid',usernameVariable:'USR',passwordVariable:'PWD')]){
                    bat "docker login -u=${env.USR} -p=${env.PWD} registry.heroku.com"
                }
                bat "heroku container:release web --app=enochjenkinstest"
        }
    }
}
```

}

The "Set up Heroku" stage is supposed to log me into heroku, for the password I plan to use an api token, I tried suggestions from [Script "heroku login" in a CI environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554697/script-heroku-login-in-a-ci-environment)  as you can see above but the inputs aren't being fed in, I get this when I reach that stage
`C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test Pipeline>(echo "${env.USR}" echo "${env.PWD}" )  | heroku login -i  heroku: Enter your login credentials Email: Password:  Password:  Password:  Password:  Password:  Password:  Password:  Password:  Password:  Password:`

This reoccurs and never ends. If there are any suggestions to fix the bat command or an alternative method I'm open to it.
I also tried creating the _nertc file and copying it to the home directory or putting it in my git repo to be pulled together.
The `docker login` in "Deploy Docker Image works fine, so I assumed it will log me into heroku automatically but it didn't
I posted my entire pipeline script incase there is something wrong elsewhere